# How to match two images using Opencv

Tags: ios, opencv

I am using open cv library to compare two images. I am already able to get difference of both images as result. But i want to get matching points of both images as result. How i can achieve this ?

Comment: if you mean feature matching you should investigate SIFT etc, very well documented on opencv website

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will check it.

Comment: Not well defined... 
What are "differences"? You could measure intensity differences in each channel. You could measure PNSR or SSIM. You could try to find out whether there is exactly same object in the images for two different views. You could try to find out whether there is similar content in both images (both show a mountain or a bird or a car or a dog with a hat). The question for "differences" or "similarities" looks very clear in the beginning but is extremely ambiguous ;)
If reduced to single points, you can add a very "similar" list of ways what "matching" means.

Comment: Thanks @Micka . My task is that i have set of images and i want to remove all moving objects from them, and create a new image based on set of images.

Comment: Are your images captured from a stationary camera? Sounds like classic background modeling/subtraction might work. Can you add a short sequence of cample images? If you stick to "difference between images" really simple intensity differences might already work for that scenario.

Comment: maybe have a look at http://www.telecom.ulg.ac.be/research/vibe/ for a background subtraction sample (afaik there is demo software) http://orbi.ulg.ac.be/handle/2268/145853

Comment: @Micka Yes images will be captured from stationary camera. "Classic background modeling/subtraction" exactly this is what i am trying to do. I can not post images at the moment. Thanks for the hints and links.

Comment: so the easiest approaches are something like MOGBackgroundSubtractor (opencv) or even easier: take 3 images in a sequence. subtract pixel values between first and second image, and between second and third image. Threshold the result (if abs(distance) > 20 or sth, say there is a change). If the same pixel shows a change in both difference images, there is a moving object at that pixel in the second input image.

Comment: @Micka ok i will try to implement code according to your instructions. Thanks for the help.